# In Azure Pipelines, is there a way to disable CI on a branch with an open PR when hosted in Azure Repos?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

We have a use case where our code is fully-hosted in Azure DevOps (Pipelines, Repos, et al).  We need to build and deploy our "full" build/deploy process to deploy a serverless function.  What we ideally want would be a single build/deploy process when a PR is open and updated.  We have a build validation policy which we would like to ignore the `Individual CI` build when the PR accepts another `push` as `Build Validation` policies should supersede the `trigger` block.

Is there a way to accomplish this since the `pr` triggers aren't available to Azure Repos?

Repo Type: Azure Repos Git

```yaml
# The pipeline will fail if a branch is not either 'main' or 'something/12345-something'
trigger:
  paths:
    exclude:
      - azure-pipelines-cleanup.yaml
      - docs
      - README.md

name: $(SourceBranchName).$(Rev:r)_$(Build.RequestedFor)

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipeline
      type: git
      name: <Org Obscured>/infra-pipeline
      ref: feature/212242-pipeline-housecleaning # this is pipeline branch ref, should be main unless testing pipeline changes

# This extends a template from the central pipeline repo
extends:
  template: service-pipeline-template.yaml@pipeline
  parameters:
    appName: starter
    publishSdk: true
```

[image: Build Validation setup]

Result: Two builds, one `Invididual CI`, one `PR automated` triggered simultaneously
[image: Double triggered builds - Individual CI, and PR automated]

Desired: Only the `PR automated` build.

This isn't an issue with a conditional expression per se unless there's a way to disable the trigger block outright while still running the full pipeline in PR. I don't imagine there's a way to run server-side git hooks in ADO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no such method could disable CI trigger only when PR trigger exists.

In Azure Devops , CI trigger and PR trigger are two independent triggers. If the trigger conditions are met at the same time, the pipeline will be triggered twice.

Here are the trigger conditions of [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) and [PR trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers).

Howerver, there is a workaround could  achieve your desired state.

You could add `[skip ci]` in the commit message when you push changes.

[image]

Then the CI trigger will be skipped. And this commit will only trigger PR trigger Build.

The following is the [equivalent commit message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits)：

> [skip ci] or [ci skip]
>
> skip-checks: true or skip-checks:true
>
> [skip azurepipelines] or [azurepipelines skip]
>
> [skip azpipelines] or [azpipelines skip]
>
> [skip azp] or [azp skip]

You can aslo submit the feature request in [Our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21).